# Comma(,) issue in string in Java

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, string, spring-boot

I am using bootstrap multiselect and in that i have multiple string values and i am passing that list of string in formData in an ajax call and in backend Spring Boot Controller i am getting that value in

```
@RequestParam("selectedNames") List<String> selectedNames
```

This is working fine for almost all scenarios but getting failed in scenario

("Eng,l's") -> This is single string  **it contains , and ' special characters**

For Example I selected three values in multiselect -

1- INDIA 2- AMERICA 3- Eng,l's

Now in Backend i am getting 4 values in selectedNames list parameter (INDIA,AMERICA,Eng,l's),

but i need only there values

Suggest me some ways to handle this specific scenario

This Code is working fine for values (AMERICA,INDIA,ENGLAND) but failing for  when i have comma in one of the selected names

[image]

```
function selectedNamesData() {
  let selectedNames = $("#selectedNames").val();
  let formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("selectedNames",selectedNames);
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "url",
    data: formData,
    success: function (data) {
      console.log(data);
    },
  });
}
```

Comment: sounds like you are not properly sending up the value

Comment: Please add the ajax call related code where you are making the call to the server

Comment: @adiga Added ajax call in question

Comment: @epascarello working for every scenario but failing for only one case